# MX Zip Files Not Working

Tags: mx-zip

I'm using the exp:channel:entries tag to add files to a zip folder, but when I try to download the zip file, I get the following error:

Error : PCLZIP_ERR_MISSING_FILE (-4) : File 'http:/www.domain.com/file_name.pdf' does not exist

However, if I go to: http:/www.domain.com/file_name.pdf, the file does exist and is shown.

Any thoughts?

Here are my tags:

```
{exp:zip direct_output="no" filename="project_package.zip" comment="Project Package" remove_path="" add_path=""}
{zip:files}
{exp:channel:entries disable="categories|member_data|pagination" limit="1"}
{project_package}
    [{project_package:project_item}]
{/project_package}
{/exp:channel:entries}
{/zip:files}
{/exp:zip}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add absolute paths or relative paths. It will not work with urls.